# Is there an Ubuntu upnp interface or api for XBMC/KODI?

Tags: sound, xbmc

I am in the process of developing a voice controlled home automation system, a big part of which is my media center...currently XBMC running a Rasberry Pi, soon to be Kodi running on a Rasberry Pi 2.  I would like to have full programmatic control allowing the user, via voice, touch, or keyboard commands to start/stop video, TV, audio, etc.  I know, from experience and from a previous question on this board that there is a somewhat limited HTTP interface controllable through a browser.  I would prefer to have the better/complete control like the Yatse, or other android or iphone remotes.

Is there anything like this available?

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a now depricated HTTP GET interface.

That said, the way to go now is JSON-RPC: http://kodi.wiki/view/JSON-RPC_API

It is usable over various transports: TCP,HTTP,locally via python and websockets. The web interface is just an extra.

I suppose this will give you more control over kodi than UPnP because it is the proprietary protocol. But i was just trying to get my head around upnp&kodi when i found your question, so...